# Invalid-feedback not apear (Server-side) (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I try to make the invalid-feedback to show when the input is blank but it seem I cant make it show. Anyone can help?

```
<!--======================================== CSS =======================================-->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--=================================== Core JS Files ==================================-->
    <script src="../js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/core/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/core/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!--===================================== Content ================================-->
    <div class="container">
        <p class="mb-4">Fill the form below to add new record on database</p>
        <form action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]); ?>" method="post" class="needs-validation">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hostelName">Hostel Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control <?= (!empty($name_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="hostelName" name="hostelName" value="<?= $name; ?>" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" >
                        <?= $name_err;?>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 80px;" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 80px;" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is MySQLi

```
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$name = $block = $level = $room = $status = "";
$name_err = $block_err = $level_err = $room_err = $status_err = "";

// Form Submit (What happen when button SUBMIT click)
if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" ) {

    // Data Validation ================================ Hostel Name ===========================================
    $input_name = trim( $_POST[ "hostelName" ] );
    
    if ( empty( $input_name ) ) 
    {
        $name_err = "Please enter a hostel name.";
    } 
    
    elseif ( !filter_var( $input_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array( "options" => array( "regexp" => "/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/" ) ) ) ) 
    {
        $name_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    }
    
    else 
    {
        $name = $input_name;
    }
```

Noted: I also try to use d-block, needs-validation, novalidate(cause server error 403 "access forbidden") still not working

Comment: Please, code is text, so post it as text, pictures make it unusable to someone trying to write an answer

Comment: This will cause problems because you use unescaped double quotes: `action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]); ?>"`, but you can remove the entire `action` attribute because the default behaviour is to submit to self. Other than that, I cannot reproduce, I can see the validation errors.

Comment: will it still work if i remove all "action" attribute

Comment: Tq to **El_Vanja** for the help, It seem problem can be solve with 2 ways, either I remove entire<pre> action<code>attribute or create a custom CSS seem can solved the problem, so I choose to create a custom CSS even it got a lot work to do, and finally i can show <pre>Invalid-feedback<code>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TQ very much for the help **El_Vanja**, I forgot that the default behavior of form is to submit to self. After I remove the action and follow/read the doc on bootstrap. I finally able to show invalid-feedback text.

```
        <form method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="hostelName">Hostel Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control <?= (!empty($name_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="hostelName" name="hostelName" value="<?= $name; ?>" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" >
                        <?= $name_err;?>
                    </div>
            </div>
```